# Using Python tesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use tesseract-ocr

I installed PIL (the binary version PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.exe)

I tried this:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('7.png'), lang='fra'))
```

but there is an error

```
Trying to load '../vs2010/DLL_Release/libtesseract302.dll'...
Trying to load 'libtesseract302.dll'...
[Error 126] The specified module could not be found
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How did you install pytesseract?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

I replaced the binary version with the one available on github